# Are there some ways to find sites linking to a specific post or works citing it?

Tags: discussion, support, hyperlinks, citation, external

Over the years, Mathematics Stack Exchange became quite popular and certainly at least some of the content provided here is rather useful. It is not surprising that many people link to some stuff posted on this site. (Including links by our own users - you can see more than 2500 [announcer badges](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/announcer), more than 100 [booster badges](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/60/booster) and more than 50 [publicist badges](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/61/publicist).)
Some posts from this site are also cited in various papers and occasionally even books.

**Question.** Are there some good ways how to find other websites which link to a specific post? How can I find papers/books citing some specific post?

The only thing I can think of is searching for some of the formats used for posts in some search engine. (By which I mean `math.stackexchange.com/questions/{id}` or `math.stackexchange.com/q/{id}` or `math.stackexchange.com/a/{id}`. To include some examples, here is such search in [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22math.stackexchange.com/questions/54506%22),
[Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22http://math.stackexchange.com/q/72322%22) and
[Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22math.stackexchange.com/q/527966%22). In each case I have chosen as an example a post which returns at least one search result.)

I also know that I can search in Wikipedia articles using Wikipedia's internal search. (Using the syntax such as
[insource:"math.stackexchange.com/a/556756"](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=insource%3A"math.stackexchange.com%2Fa%2F556756"&title=Special:Search&profile=advanced&fulltext=1&ns0=1&ns1=1&searchToken=7c2iad9b21m1brrtz1tdw85pg).)

Other than that, I do not have many ideas how to search for resources citing/linkin to some specific post form this site.

Comment: "math.stackexchange.com/questions/54506" -site:stackexchange.com -site:stackoverflow.com will give search results that exculde stackexchange.com and stackoverflow.com

Comment: Some posts on Meta Stack Exchange that seem related: [Can I see where Publicist badges were linked *from*?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146584), [Mechanism to track shares](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94212), [Is there any analytics information that moderators can access for individual questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77138). There is also a declined feature request: [Announcer Badge list to show referrers to the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279428).

Comment: "[backlink checker](https://www.google.ca/search?q=backlink+checker)"?