# Finding who has linked to an answer of mine

Tags: support, search, up-votes, linked-questions

I just received three upvotes for [a seven-year-old answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88280/1508). Obviously somebody has recently linked to it in a question or answer. Is there any way for me to find this link? I'm curious!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the sidebar on the right there is a colon 'related' and also a colon 'linked' if there are posts that  link to the current one.

There I found [If $f(x) \geq 0$, then $g(x) =f(x)+f'(x)+f''(x)+...+f^r(x) \geq 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3130067/) which is very recent.

Of course this only works if the post is linked on this site. Otherwise searching for the ID-number of the post, or rather that of the associated question in case of an answer, can be a way to find links.

Comment: Related to the last paragraph: [Are there some ways to find sites linking to a specific post or works citing it?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28456)

Comment: I never noticed that Linked sidebar before! How could I have missed it? Thanks for the tip!